# IP gets blocked for a few minutes after some failed SSH login attempts

Tags: ssh, login, password, pam

After a few incorrect login attempts (using password), my IP gets blocked and I am unable to SSH into the Ubuntu server for a few minutes.

I don't want that to happen (at least for my IP). In fact, I want to whitelist my IP on my server. But I don't know where to do it. I have ufw disabled. I don't use `fail2ban`, I don't use `pam_tally` or `pam_faillock`. I have installed `libpam-google-authenticator` for 2 factor authentication and `pam_cracklib.so` for strong password policy. In fact, I don't even know what is blocking my IP for the failed attempts. I have the below files in my `/etc/pam.d`

```
 atd
 chfn
 chpasswd
 chsh
 common-account
 common-auth
 common-password
 common-session
 common-session-noninteractive
 cron
 login
 newusers
 other
 passwd
 polkit-1
 runuser
 runuser-l
 sshd
 su
 sudo
 systemd-user
 vmtoolsd
```

Could anyone please tell me what do I have to do so that my IP does not get blocked for authentication failures?

In `sshd_config` file I have set `MaxAuthTries 20`. But ssh fails within 8 wrong attempts. And there is nothing about blocktime or whitelisting.

Last time when this happened the last few entries from /var/log/auth.log looked like below.

```
Aug 26 15:04:24 Bastion sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2661]: Did not receive verification code from user
Aug 26 15:04:24 Bastion-ip-10-0-1-45 sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[2661]: Invalid verification code for username
Aug 26 15:04:26 Bastion sshd[2657]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for username from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Aug 26 15:04:27 Bastion sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[3247]: Did not receive verification code from user
Aug 26 15:04:27 Bastion sshd(pam_google_authenticator)[3247]: Invalid verification code for username
Aug 26 15:04:29 Bastion sshd[2657]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for username from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IP getting blocked.

Comment: a maximum number of attempts is probably configured in the configuration file of the SSH Server

Comment: Use an ssh key with a password, then the failure will be locally on the key and not on the server.

Comment: Do you have Fail2Ban set up?  Fail2ban is usually what blocks your IP for some time after a certain number of failed logins.  Also, use SSH Key authentication, it's much more effective and can be used in place of password authentication (and is much harder to bruteforce)

Comment: The reason for blocking will be in /var/log/. When you are on the server connect over another session, When it is blocked do a `ls -ltr /var/log/` and check the files that look like that could be related to your block at the bottom with `tail -n 100 {file}`  (syslog for instance or an ssh log if you have one).

Comment: @rtaft I want to use password with 2FA. Its a server which has to be accessed by many users. Sometimes from the same IP.

Comment: I can see where this would be a big problem if the server is behind a NAT and it sees all incoming connections coming from the same IP.

Comment: Are there any customization to iptables?  It's possible to block too many incoming connections to ssh from the same ip with that.

Comment: Are you deploying some form of Fail2Ban or 2FA functionality like through Duo that implements IP level blocks as part of their cloud service for failed auths?  If so, you have to be careful with NAT at play because it may obfuscate the source IP and not show it right.  Without your logfile data we can't really determine what actually is happening with the blocks though...

Comment: I checked. iptables are fine. the server is not behind NAT. Set MaxAuthTries to 9999. I used to use fail2ban. but I uninstalled it a long time back. Couldn't this be due to anything related to PAM?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue. It was OSSEC. I had an ossec-hids agent also installed in the server. The active-response feature in the ossec was blocking IP for ssh failures. It was fixed by adding the IP to be ignored inside global block <white_list>1.2.3.4</white_list> in ossec.conf file in ossec manager. Thanks for all the helpful tips guys.